# Saving api endpoint request to DB using Entity Framework

Tags: c#, json, serialization

I have been doing a lot of searching and have yet to find any relevant information about this issue. I was wondering if anyone could point me in the right direction as to how i can achieve the following:

So what I'm attempting to do, is to make a api endpoint request and saving the results into a database on my end.

Here's my controller:

```
public class Reference_ManufacturersController : ApiController
{
    private DataEntities db = new DataEntities();
    static string _address = "http://localhost:57454/api/Reference_Manufacturers?format=json";
    private Reference_Manufacturers result;

    // GET: api/Reference_Manufacturers
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Reference_Manufacturers>> GetReference_Manufacturers()
    {
        Reference_Manufacturers resultset = await GetResponse();
        db.Reference_Manufacturers.Add(resultset);
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return db.Reference_Manufacturers;
    }

    private async Task<Reference_Manufacturers> GetResponse()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_address);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<Reference_Manufacturers>();
        return result;
    }
}
```

What happens when I run this is that I get the following exception:

> ExceptionMessage
>
> Cannot deserialize the current JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) into type 'DIA_FirearmsAPIversion2.Models.Reference_Manufacturers' because the type requires a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) to deserialize correctly. To fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) or change the deserialized type to an array or a type that implements a collection interface (e.g. ICollection, IList) like List that can be deserialized from a JSON array. JsonArrayAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON array. Path '', line 1, position 1.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Can you show an example of the json?

Comment: [Link](http://i693.photobucket.com/albums/vv293/saturobi360/ReferenceManufacturer_zpszktksoqf.jpg)

Comment: Pretty sure the json you get back from `_address` can't be mapped to `Reference_Manufacturers`

Comment: I noticed that when i change the _address value to: 
http://localhost:57454/api/Reference_Manufacturers/1000022?format=json
 to point to a specific Reference_Manufacturers value the result gets saved to the DB.

The issue here is that im looking to use the original _address value as posted in the Original post to save a collection of Reference_Manufacturers values into the DB.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out what i was overlooking and doing wrong.
I did not use a container of sorts to hold all the returned values.

```
public class Reference_ManufacturersController : ApiController
{
    private DataEntities db = new DataEntities();
    static string _address = "http://localhost:57454/api/Reference_Manufacturers?format=json";
    private List<Reference_Manufacturers> result;

    // GET: api/Reference_Manufacturers
    public async Task<IEnumerable<Reference_Manufacturers>> GetReference_Manufacturers()
    {
        List<Reference_Manufacturers> resultset = await GetResponse();
        foreach (Reference_Manufacturers manu in resultset)
        {
            db.Reference_Manufacturers.Add(manu);
        }
        await db.SaveChangesAsync();
        return db.Reference_Manufacturers;
    }

    private async Task<List<Reference_Manufacturers>> GetResponse()
    {
        var client = new HttpClient();
        HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(_address);
        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
        result = await response.Content.ReadAsAsync<List<Reference_Manufacturers>>();
        return result;
    }}
```